# Get specific attributes of object for graphing

Tags: javascript, object, d3.js

I am trying to use D3 to graph time-dependent data. The file I import has multiple channels. I want to display each channel of data on the graph.

I'm trying to format the var "dataset" so that d3 can recognize it as a list of numbers to graph.

Grabbing the data:

```
var dataset = d3.tsv("/Data/"+`${fridge}`+getInstrumentURL(instrumentArray[1]))
.then( data => 
{ 
    data.forEach( d => 
    {
        d['Date  Time'] = new Date(d['Date  Time']);
        d.Tpt1 = +d.Tpt1;
        d.Tpt2 = +d.Tpt2;
        d.Tstill = +d.Tstill;
        d.Tdblstill = +d.Tdblstill;
        d.Tcp = +d.Tcp;
        d.Tmc = +d.Tmc;
        d.Tsamp = +d.Tsamp;
    }); 
    console.log(data); 
});  // converts strings to numbers. Console log confirms my data transfer.
```

Graphing:

```
var svg = d3.select("graph").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("path")  //lines connecting data points
    .datum(dataset)  //here i want to use channel Tpt1, Tpt2, etc.
    .attr("class", "line") 
    .attr("d", line);

svg.selectAll(".dot")  //data POINTS
    .data(dataset)
    .enter().append("circle") // Uses the enter().append() method
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return xScale(i) })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.y) })
    .attr("r", 5)
```

just as "dataset": page loads, no data in graph.
As `dataset[]['Tpt1']`: page loads incorrectly
As `dataset['Tpt1']`: undefined error. I know why this is wrong (index), but how do I pass the entire array so that every Tpt1 value gets graphed?

I am trying to use this Bl.ocks example but with a TSV: https://bl.ocks.org/gordlea/27370d1eea8464b04538e6d8ced39e89

Comment: Please don't use backticks for large blocks of code. Also, try to make the code as clear for potential answerers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the question, but looking at the this line:

`var dataset = d3.tsv('/yourpath...')`

you are not understanding how the asynchronous `tsv()` function works because it will always return undefined to the `dataset` variable. The data will only become available when the `Promise` set up by `d3.tsv()` is resolved and the callback function in `then()` is executed.

You should put the code that builds you vizualization in a function so that you can call it inside the callback of the `then()` function when you get the data, as I've shown below.

```
// Define you code that builds the vizualization within a function that
// accepts your dataset as an argument. This function can then be called
// whenever you have access to your data.
function buildMyViz(data) {
  var svg = d3.select('graph')
  ... etc
}

var dataset; // Define dataset outside of your request for data
d3.tsv('/yourpath...').then(function(returnedData) {

  // When the data is returned (asynchronously), you can assign it to dataset
  dataset = returnedData;

  // Now you have the data you can trigger the code that builds the d3 viz
  buildMyViz(dataset);
});
```

Comment: So I took that line form the linked example. I've actually rewritten so that all my handling is in the async function.

My question is how do I access the data column correctly.

Comment: But in the linked example he is assigning to the dataset variable from a *synchronous* function. So it is different to the *asynchronous* flow that results from using `d3.tsv()`. Can you update your question to show how you have re-written your code? I'm still not sure what you mean by "how do I access the *data column* correctly. What do you mean by data column?

Comment: I've rephrased my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498463/accessing-the-correct-array-of-objects-column